# Install packages globallly

Tags: package, package-repositories

Is this something that can / should be done? For example, often I use emacs in my user account and sometimes root account. When using the package manager (i.e marmalade or something) do I have to install the same packages seperately for each account? It seems to me that they get installed in your home directory.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by Nsukami, package.el does support system-wide packages.  But as your subsequent question points out, it does not provide any special help to *install* packages in a system-wide manner.

One way you can do that is by using something like:

```
(setq package-user-dir "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa")
```

in your root account's `~/.emacs`.  This will make the root user's installed packages available to all users (since `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa` should normally appear in the default value of `package-directory-list`).

Comment: Yes this makes sense! Great help guys - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

> package-directory-list's value is
>   ("/usr/local/share/emacs/24.4/site-lisp/elpa"
>   "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa"
>   "/usr/share/emacs/24.4/site-lisp/elpa"
>   "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa")
>
> This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation: List of additional directories containing Emacs Lisp
>   packages. Each directory name should be absolute.
>
> These directories contain packages intended for system-wide; in
>   contrast, `package-user-dir' contains packages for personal use.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 24.1 of Emacs.

Another [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Files.html#Package-Files):

> In addition to package-user-dir, Emacs looks for installed packages in
>   the directories listed in package-directory-list. These directories
>   are meant for system administrators to make Emacs packages available
>   system-wide; Emacs itself never installs packages there.

So, for site wide install, I suggest you to, as a system administrator, manually install the packages inside /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa. Or you can also do as suggested by @Stefan

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can confirm on inspection of package-directory-list value it is as you have described and indeed package-user-dir is the .emacs.d/elpa folder - where the packages are currently being installed. So I ask then do I override the package-user-dir to point to the global location, or when using for example 'M-x package-install' how can I tell it I want a site wide installation?