# Avoid installing package to ".emacs.d/elpa/" directory

Tags: use-package, load-path

I install yasnippet from the repository using the package manager and I add the corresponding directory to the load path before (use-package yasnippet):

```lisp
    ;; Add all subdirs in site-lisp to the load-path
    (let ((default-directory "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/"))
      (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

but when I start emacs it installs the package (despite of the load path) in the ".emacs.d/elpa/" directory.
Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install packages globallly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17558/install-packages-globallly)

Comment: @matteol it is not an duplicate of the linked question

Comment: @Banish It should not do this, could you show your `use-package` sexp for yasnippet? When running emacs without your config `emacs -q`, is `yasnippet` available? (it should, because it is loaded by system wide emacs init scripts)

Comment: @jue Do you mean init.el configuration for yasnippet:

;; Yasnippet
;; check documentation for all scripts for the corresponding language
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure t
  :init
  (yas-global-mode 1)
  )

Answer (score 0):

When I execute the following lisp code:

```lisp
(print load-path)
```

I get the list of all directories in the load path including /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ with all subdirectories.
I've tried the following:

```lisp
;; Undo Tree
;; using C-x u to choose and q to quit/undo/ to the step
(use-package undo-tree
  :ensure t
  :init
  (global-undo-tree-mode)
  )
```

and the package was automatically installed in "~/.emacs.d/elpa/".
but when I've commented the ":ensure t" and delete the package from ".../elpa" but installed wit the package manager to "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/" I still had the undo-tree package but from the common directory.

```lisp
(use-package undo-tree
  :init
  (progn
    (require 'undo-tree)
    (global-undo-tree-mode)
    ))
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Of course, this is what the `:ensure` keyword is for. Read at the [use-package documentation](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#package-installation)